# How to set or grant SELECTINAUTH for a schema in DB2 11.5

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-11.5

I'm running DB2 11.5 and want to grant select, insert, update or delete rights for all tables in a specific schema. SELECTINAUTH etc. seems to be perfect for this.

When I'm looking to the SYSCAT.SCHEMAAUTH Catalog View I can see the following columns:

- ALTERINAUTH
- CREATEINAUTH
- DROPINAUTH
- SELECTINAUTH
- INSERTINAUTH
- UPDATEINAUTH
- DELETEINAUTH

The first 3 privileges can be granted by e.g. GRANT ALTERINAUTH ON SCHEMA  TO USER . But this don't work for the last 4 columns.

The Knowledge Center tells that this are implicit privileges, but I can't find any hint, how a user or a group can get this privileges implicit or explicit.

Does anybody know when or how e.g. INYSERTINAUT is set to Y?

Comment: This functionality isn't out yet.

Comment: At the database level you can grant data access, but that is regardless of schema

Comment: It's available as a technical preview at the moment with 11.5. You should ask your IBM rep on how to enable it, if you are interested. It should work as it works with Db2 Warehouse now. [GRANT (schema privileges) statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCJDQ/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000964.html).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your answers. I already reached out to IBM support, but didn't get any response yet.

@MarkBarinstein: Thank you for the link. I will add it to my support ticket. It should help IBM to find the answer. :-)

Comment: Tell them, that it's some new db2 registry variable controlling this functionality.

Comment: Yes @MarkBarinstein, IBM told me "So currently the usage of SELECTINAUTH, INSERTINAUTH, UPDATEINAUTH is only available in DB2 Warehouse" and "Schema authorization is one of these features and we have publicly stated (at IDUG conferences etc) that we will be brought to Db2 in an update to 11.5.". 

It can be enabled with db2set DB2_ENABLE_SCHEMA_AUTHORIZATION=true, but it's not documented and therefore not supported yet. (as IBM explained).

Comment: Well, this means that IBM allowed you to test this functionality. So, good luck!

Comment: @Cyberider you might want to post your comment above as an answer, it's useful.

Comment: @mustaccio I also added it as an answer. A little bit late as I was on vacation, but it's done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following information from IBM: "So currently the usage of SELECTINAUTH, INSERTINAUTH, UPDATEINAUTH is only available in DB2 Warehouse" and "Schema authorization is one of these features and we have publicly stated (at IDUG conferences etc) that we will be brought to Db2 in an update to 11.5.".

It can be enabled with `db2set DB2_ENABLE_SCHEMA_AUTHORIZATION=true`, but it's not documented and therefore not supported yet. (as IBM explained).

Comment: Schema privileges and authorities was rolled out with DB2 11.5. Mod Pack 5. [link](https://ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=v1155-security-enhancements)